# schenkerian analysis archive

Tags: theory, analysis, schenker

I would like to know if there is something like an Archive of Schenkerian Analysis of most pieces of music, or, at least, some kind of analysis. If you want to analyse an important piece of music, I think its almost sure it has been analysed before, but I don't know where to find it. Even if there is no a complete analysis, there must be articles about it. Do you know what are the main resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when a scholar makes a serious analysis of a musical piece, it's part of a larger piece of scholarship. I'm afraid there's no single "central database" of analysis, but there are many places to find musical scholarship. There are scholarly journals that specialize in music theory (like the *Journal of Music Theory*), and these might contain articles that focus on a single piece. There are search engines that can target a collection of musical journals or their abstracts, and a librarian can help you access them. You're more likely, though, to find a piece discussed in a larger context, perhaps comparing it to other pieces, perhaps making a point about a certain musical feature or trend. You might also find analyses in a book-length work focusing on a single composer. In short, you just have to do the good old-fashioned research work of searching the body of scholarly sources.